# How to make text up and under the transform widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: UI Concept]

I'm trying to make this particular UI and I can't figure out how to create the 'Playlist for you:' and 'Playlist of the week' up and down the transform widget respectively.

This is my main.dart file.

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:secondlife_mobile/PageViewHolder.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Perspective PageView',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late PageViewHolder holder;
  late PageController _controller;
  double fraction =
      0.57; // By using this fraction, we're telling the PageView to show the 50% of the previous and the next page area along with the main page

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    holder = PageViewHolder(value: 2.0);
    _controller = PageController(initialPage: 2, viewportFraction: fraction);
    _controller.addListener(() {
      holder.setValue(_controller.page);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Perspective PageView"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 1,
            child: ChangeNotifierProvider<PageViewHolder>.value(
              value: holder,
              child: PageView.builder(
                  controller: _controller,
                  itemCount: 4,
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return MyPage(
                      number: index.toDouble(),
                      fraction: fraction,
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final number;
  final double? fraction;

  const MyPage({super.key, this.number, this.fraction});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double? value = Provider.of<PageViewHolder>(context).value;
    double diff = (number - value);
    // diff is negative = left page
    // diff is 0 = current page
    // diff is positive = next page

    //Matrix for Elements
    final Matrix4 pvMatrix = Matrix4.identity()
      ..setEntry(3, 2, 1 / 0.9) //Increasing Scale by 90%
      ..setEntry(1, 1, fraction!) //Changing Scale Along Y Axis
      ..setEntry(3, 0, 0.004 * -diff); //Changing Perspective Along X Axis

    final Matrix4 shadowMatrix = Matrix4.identity()
      ..setEntry(3, 3, 1 / 1.6) //Increasing Scale by 60%
      ..setEntry(3, 1, -0.004) //Changing Scale Along Y Axis
      ..setEntry(3, 0, 0.002 * diff) //Changing Perspective along X Axis
      ..rotateX(1.309); //Rotating Shadow along X Axis

    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
      children: [
        Transform.translate(
          offset: const Offset(0.0, -47.5),
          child: Transform(
            transform: pvMatrix,
            alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                  blurRadius: 11.0,
                  spreadRadius: 4.0,
                  offset: const Offset(
                      13.0, 35.0), // shadow direction: bottom right
                )
              ]),
              child: Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/image_${number.toInt() + 1}.jpg",
                  fit: BoxFit.fill),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Emulator]

And this is how the result of the main.dart file looks like.

I've tried implementing the Column widget with a Text near the Stack widget but my vscode responded that it is a dead code.

I would be very grateful if I could figure out this problem :)

Comment: We still can't get what you want to achieve, Is it the text(name of the playlist) that you'd like to be on the image?

Comment: No, I mean I want to implement the 'Playlist for you:' and 'Playlist of the week' text just like the first image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your body in a Column() preceded by a SingleChildScrollView() coz you'll have to scroll vertically too with it's content not overflowing the screen

```
body:SingleChildScrollView(
    child: SizedBox(
          height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
         child: Column(
               crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.start,
             children:[
       ////Your Playlist for you text
              Text('Playlist for you'),
             const SizedBox(height:15.0),
             Container(
        child: Center(
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 1,
            child: ChangeNotifierProvider<PageViewHolder>.value(
              value: holder,
              child: PageView.builder(
                  controller: _controller,
                  itemCount: 4,
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return MyPage(
                      number: index.toDouble(),
                      fraction: fraction,
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ), 
       const SizedBox(height:15.0),
       ////Your Playlist of the week text
              Text('Playlist of the week'),
             
         ],
       ),
     ),
   ),
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help!
One more question, I'm trying to modify the position of the text with 'textAlign: Alignment()' but, the folllowing error shows up. 

The argument type 'Alignment' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TextAlign?'

How should I deal with this error?